# Yoast. Display metadesc in categories

Tags: wordpress, meta, yoast

I want to display metadesc in my category’s pages like this:

```
 echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), ‘_yoast_wpseo_metadesc’, true);
```

It works in posts, but doesn’t work in categories.
In categories I write:

```
 $category = get_queried_object();
 $cat_id = $category->term_id;
 echo get_term_meta($cat_id, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true);
```

How can I show metadesc in categories?

Answer (score 1):

Use [WPSEO_Taxonomy_Meta::get_term_meta](https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/yoast/function/WPSEO_Taxonomy_Meta::get_term_meta).

Your example:

```
$category = get_queried_object();
$cat_id = $category->term_id;
echo WPSEO_Taxonomy_Meta::get_term_meta($cat_id, 'product_cat', 'title');
```